# Prove that abc=0 given some conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

Let $a,b,c$ be  real numbers such that $a+b+c= 1$, $a^2+b^2+c^2 =1$ and $a^3+b^3+ c^3 =1$. We have to prove that $a bc = 0$. Can I prove it in following way, is this correct:

$ a +b +c = 1  / ^2 $

$ a^2+b^2+c^2 + 2 (a b+ b c + a c )= 1 \implies ab +bc + ac =0 $

Now we multiply the last equality by $a,b,c $ respectively:

$a ^2 b +abc+a^2c =0 $

$a b^2 + b^2 c + ab c=0 $

$abc+bc^2 + ac^2 =0$

Now I multiply: $(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2) = 1 \implies a^2 b +  a^2 c +a b^2 + b^2 c +a c^2+b c^2 =0$

Then when I add the previous 3 equalities,it follows that $abc=0$. Can someone just check if this method is correct, especially the part when I multiply by $a,b,c$, are we allowed to do so? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Where are your doubts? Multiplying by some scalar? Why not?

Comment: I mean, if some of a,b,c is 0

Comment: In the end because abc=0, it means that some of them must be 0, but in this part, when I don't know which one is 0, is multiplication ok?

Comment: Yes, multiplying an equation by zero is still correct, right? It gives $0=0$.

Comment: Ok, so this method is correct. Thanks!

Comment: I edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively we can use:

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$$

$$=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)+c^3-3abc$$

$$=(a+b+c)((a+b)^2+c^2-c(a+b))-3ab(a+b+c)$$

$$=\cdots$$

$$=(a+b+c)((a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca))$$

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way.

Knowing that $a+b+c=1$ and that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2 (a b+a c+b c)$$
we get $$ab+ac+bc= 0$$
and as $a^3+b^3+c^3=1$ and we have
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3-3 (a b+a c+b c) (a+b+c)+3 a b c$$
we conclude that $$abc=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials) give

$$
\begin{aligned}
e_{1}&=p_{1}=1
\\2e_{2}&=e_{1}p_{1}-p_{2}=0
\\3abc=3e_{3}&=e_{2}p_{1}-e_{1}p_{2}+p_{3}=0\end{aligned}
$$

(In particular,  $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3-x^2$ and so are $0,0,1$ up to permutation. But the question doesn't ask for the values of $a,b,c$ nor are they needed.)